# What is the definition of "single statement" in C++?

Tags: c++

Identify a statement that is false for the given snippet:

```
int n = 1 + 2;
```

A. 1 and 2 are operands.

B. + is operator.

C. ; marks the end of a statement in C++.

D. It is a single statement.

Comment: Aren't all of these true?

Comment: Is variable declaration a statement?

Comment: @Eugene Yes. It is a declaration statement.

Comment: @SuperStormer -- I'm inclined to agree with you. The question is badly written. Yes, the `;` "for the given snippet" marks the end of a statement. On the other hand, "`;` marks the end of a statement in C++" is overly broad, and not true.

Comment: The awfully-worded question even uses the term "statement" to identify "It is a single statement".

Comment: In the name of clarity - the question being asked here is "What is the definition of 'single statement' in C++?".  Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is C.

The grammar production for a `for` statement is

> for ( init-statement condition<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ) statement

So, in

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

the first `;` ends the "init-statement". The second `;` is part of the `for` loop grammar, and does not end a statement.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is C.

`while (false){}`, for example, is a statement that does not require a semicolon.

You can even write an entire program in C++ without a semicolon:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    if (std::cout << "Hello World"){
    }
    // returning zero is implicit in main
}
```

Although really, knowing this is not going to make you a better C++ programmer. Contributing to open source projects or getting a job in the field would.

Comment: Oh, I see. (C) doesn't mean the above code.

Comment: For some reason, I laughed hard by reading the last paragraph. Good to see some humor on SO. Although I would say C++ is all about details and knowing the smaller things helps anyone to be a better coder.

Comment: `while (false){}, for example, is a statement that does not require a semicolon.` But that doesn't contradict with C. A semicolon can mark the end of a statement, even though not all statements are terminated by a semicolon. And especially, the statement isn't false for the given snippet.

Comment: @eerorika: I read it as "; marks the end of every statement in C++". For me it's the only one that can be not true. I don't think you can make a case for D, even if you attempt to define "single statement". To be honest it was an unmissable opportunity to wheel out the exotic "Hello World" program.

Comment: @Bathsheba No, there's no case for D being correct, but there is a case for the question being bogus :)